# Is a person masturbating in a public bathroom/office bathroom committting an offense?

Tags: privacy, sexual-offences

I was always led to believe that public masturbation only covers places where there isn't an expectation of privacy that people work and hang around (i.e. parks, supermarkets, hospital) so it would be illegal for a person to engage in sexual activity here.

But what if an employee at a store or office masturbates in the public bathrooms and someone comes in, would that be considered public indecency? Would it make a difference if they left bodily fluids on the toilet/floor?

Comment: Laws vary around the world, which jurisdiction (country, province, state etc) does this relate to?

Comment:  why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

- **What if an employee at a store or office masturbates in the public bathrooms?**

**[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)**

Sexual activity in a public lavatory is an offence contrary to [s.71 of the Sexual Offences Act 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/71?timeline=false):

> (1) A person commits an offence if -
>
> (a) he is in a lavatory to which the public or a section of the public has or is permitted to have access, whether on payment or otherwise,
>
> (b) he intentionally engages in an activity, and,
>
> (c) the activity is [sexual](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/78?timeline=false).
>
> (2) For the purposes of this section, an activity is sexual if a reasonable person would, in all the circumstances but regardless of any person’s purpose, consider it to be sexual.
>
> (3) A person guilty of an offence under this section is liable on summary conviction, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding 6 months or a fine not exceeding level 5 on the standard scale or both.

- **Would it make a difference if they left bodily fluids on the toilet/floor?**

No. There is no requirement to produce bodily fluids for this offence to be committed.

- **Would that be considered public indecency?**

No, unless there is an intent to cause "alarm or distress" as required by [s.66 of the 2003 Act](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/66?timeline=false):

> (1) A person commits an offence if—
>
> (a) he intentionally exposes his genitals, and
>
> (b) he intends that someone will see them and be caused alarm or distress.

Comment: What's your source regarding that a reasonable person would consider masturbation sexual activity? I would argue that sexual activity _must_ involve two or more persons.

Comment: @Greendrake What is your source that it requires two or more persons?

Comment: @JoeW Definition of "sexual": "_relating to the instincts, physiological processes, and activities connected with physical attraction or intimate physical contact **between individuals**_".

Comment: @Greendrake I would argue that masturbation is entirely a sexual act.

Comment: @Greendrake The ultimate source will be the Magistrate having due regard to the s.71 points-to-prove and the definition of [sexual](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/78?timeline=false)  - neither of which require (in the OP's scenario) more than one person to commit this offence

Comment: @Greendrake arguing about the sexual nature of masturbation will get you nowhere.  The critical factor here is not about the dictionary definition of "sexual," because that definition explicitly does not apply for the purpose of this statute.  Rather, the question is whether "a reasonable person would, in all the circumstances but regardless of any person’s purpose, consider [the act] to be sexual."  So if people would tend to think that the act allegedly performed by the accused is sexual, then it is, for the purpose of this law, sexual.

Comment: @Greendrake but since this is hypothetical, let's consider dictionary definitions.  Can you find one for "masturbate" that does not use the word "sexual" or some other form of the word "sex"?  I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

It’s possible that this could amount to Offensive Conduct within the meaning of [s4](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1988-025#sec.4) of the *Summary Offences Act* 1988.

> A person must not conduct himself or herself in an offensive manner in or near, or within view or hearing from, a public place or a school.

A bathroom that is open to the public would qualify such as one at a park or a shopping centre. It’s not clear that a bathroom solely for the use of employees is a “public place”.

Comment: The question presumes that the person has locked the door and is not visible to anyone. How would the law you cited deem masturbation any more "offensive" than urination or defecation?

Comment: @Greendrake Are they doing this silently? There are issues besides being seen or not.

Comment: @JoeW They _may_ do it silently. For that's sake, people often are not silent at all when urinating or defecating.

Comment: @Greendrake I don't think anyone is saying people don't make noises in the bathroom but lets be real here in order for this question to even matter it means someone has to have been caught doing it. That means either they where seen, heard or left evidence behind.

Comment: @JoeW For someone to be "caught", the act needs to be offensive in the first place. Whether masturbation is offensive is what is being argued.

Comment: @Greendrake What are you talking about? If no one knows you are masturbating in the bathroom nothing will ever happen. The question about it being offensive or not can only ask if they are caught and if they are not seen doing it that leave being heard doing it or leaving evidence behind. My point with the comment wasn't if it was offensive or but being seen or not isn't the only thing that matters.